# Fixed day in different years lists with Low Events

Tags: low-events

I'm using a Low Events field to store member birthdays, it's easy to calculate ages, display all members who were born in a given year, etc... and even to account for deceased members if necessary with the end date, but I'm having problems making a list of birthdays on a given day, ie, display everyone who was born on September 10th, is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

I'm using EE 2.9 and the latest versions of add-ons, I have Low Search too, just in case it helps any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I over-complicated the solution. Using the search parameter on a channel:entries or low_events:entries solves the problem. I knew I was missing something.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version (1.4.0) also supports displaying events as anniversaries with `anniversaries="yes"`, see http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events/docs/tags#entries-tag